# Android Studio: App is crashing after running it on my smartphone

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

On every app start there is a error message on my phone: "The Application was ended, sorry". What can I do now? I already searched the web and I tried to solve it, but I didn't found a answer.

This is my logcat output:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: mycompany.kopfrechnenti1907_1839, PID: 524
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{mycompany.kopfrechnenti1907_1839/mycompany.kopfrechnenti1907_1839.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:158)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5521)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:804)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:666)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:120)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:155)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:31)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:55)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV23.java:33)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:203)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:185)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:190)
  at mycompany.kopfrechnenti1907_1839.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:10)
  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1069)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2353)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:158) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5521) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnplus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnplus);
    RatingBar ratingbar = (RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void plusonclick()
    {
        if (ratingbar.getRating() == 1)
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_plusrechnenlvl1);
        }
    }

}
```

My English skills are not the best, but I hope you can understand me :)

Thank you very much!

Jul

Comment: Tip for the next time: German translations are not necessary here

Comment: Thanks! :) I'm new here and didn't Know the exactly translation :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to write following in `onCreate` after

```
setContentView()
Button btnplus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnplus);
    RatingBar ratingbar = (RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
```

like below.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnplus;
    RatingBar ratingbar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     btnplus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnplus);
     ratingbar = (RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
    }

    public void plusonclick()
    {
        if (ratingbar.getRating() == 1)
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_plusrechnenlvl1);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! :)